# Why do this css for a dropdown doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to do a dropdown menu but the `nav ul li:hover > ul` doesn't word and I don't know why please help

**css**

```
<body>

  <header>
    <!-- menu -->
    <nav id="nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Chapters</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">chapter.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">chapter.2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </nav>
  </header>

</body>
```

**html**

```
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inherit;
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D ohhhhh okay i put the ul inside the li thank you so much

Comment: @Deadpool Please don't correct the code in the question since it completly invalidates the question in the first place.

Comment: @Paulie_D - The answer was correct, and I edited to make it a better one. There was nothing wrong with it, if you check out.

Comment: Your answer was *partially* correct since it only solved some of the issues. However, you should still NOT edit code questions to "correct" them since that is not the code the OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid, `li` MUST be the direct child of a `ul`. Your first `li` is not in a ul`.

Secondly, your submenu should be inside the `li`, not after it

```css
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- menu -->
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Chapters</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">chapter.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">chapter.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: @Pauli_D - Your 2nd point is okay for good practise, but it isn't wrong. What if someone, wants to keep them as siblings, not as children of li? Though, that is not recommended, but its not wrong! --Even that too will work, beautifully.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it for you. Your `CSS selector` was wrong. See updated answer.

Also,

- li should only be used inside either `ul` or `ol`, so fix this in your HTML code.

```css
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul li:hover + ul {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header>
    <!-- menu -->
    <nav id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Chapters</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">chapter.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">chapter.2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

</body>
```